# Visual Query Tab missing

Tags: 2sxc

I am trying to create a Visual Query on a content type but I seem to be missing the tab to click into it and create it. Do I need to activate it somewhere? Or is this a bug?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ET6WO.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fsium.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5Cjy.png

Answer (score 0):

This is because the content-app doesn't have these features. This is by design, as the UI and the desired use-case is different for the Content area compared to the Apps.